# call requires api level 24 (current min is 16): android.icu.text.DecimalFormat#DecimalFormat

Tags: android-studio

Estava tentando formatar a numeração de saída dos dados dos calculos no textview, para duas casas decimais. Encontrei o código de DecimalFormat, contudo não funcionou comigo.

Já fui no Gradle e mudei o SDK minimo para 16, mas mesmo assim não deu certo. Alguém pode ajudar? Obrigada!

**Foto do erro**
[image: Código]

**Gradle**

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "uerj.dcad"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0'
}
```

Comment: Fiquei preocupada com isso também, porque ai vou limitar o aplicativo para poucas pessoas. Obrigada!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com a documentação, o `android.icu.text.DecimalFormat#DecimalFormat` está disponível somente para API 24+ e não funcionará no seu projeto, a não ser que você altere o `minSdkVersion` para 24.

Talvez você precise simplesmente inserir o [**`DecimalFormat`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) que suporte no seu projeto. Apenas importe essa classe:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat
```

E não essa:

```
import android.icu.text.DecimalFormat
```

Veja mais detalhes [**na documentação**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/text/DecimalFormat.html).

Comment: Showww!!!! Super deu certo! Obrigada!!

Comment: @AnaWaldila estamos por ae! o/